# I am trying to harden our Ubuntu 14.04 server. Can I delete some builtin system users

Tags: 14.04, server, permissions

I am relatively new to managing Ubuntu servers.  I am currently trying to harden our webserver.  I have noticed that the following users are setup on the server and I believe they are default users that were created when the system was setup.  I am curious if I can delete these users without causing harm.  Also, do these users cause any security issues. The users include: games, new, list, backup, uucp, proxy, messagebus, lp.

Finally, there are some other users that previous adminstrators setup.  Is there a way that I can see if they are actually being used by a service or if they are safe to delete.  I appreciate any insight.

Thanks
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, do these users cause any security issues

No. Most of them are system daemon and can't actually log in anyways. `nobody` and `nogroup` are special cases. `ntp` is for time synch. You disable those by disabling the *service*, not the user.

The [Linux Standard Base Core Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) specifies that UID values in the range 0 to 99 should be *statically allocated by the system*, and shall not be created by applications, while UIDs from 100 to 499 should be reserved for dynamic allocation by system administrators and post install scripts

> I am curious if I can delete these users without causing harm

Yes, but with caution and I would advice against it if only for maintenance in the future. There are some noteworthy names: `lp` is for printermanagement for instance and might be needed. You can also lock a user ...

```
 passwd {username} -l
```

and to unlock ...

```
 passwd {username} -u
```

You can also set an impossible to guess password on these account (20+ characters). Both will have the system complain about permissions or access and will alert you if they are used.

> Is there a way that I can see if they are actually being used by a service or if they are safe to delete.

Have a look at `/var/log` and specifically `syslog`. Als the command `last` to see the last time a username was used to login.

Answer (score 1):

Pasting from https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ch12.en.html

> 12.1.12.1 Are all system users necessary?
>
> Yes and no. Debian comes with some predefined users (user id (UID) <
>   99 as described in Debian Policy or /usr/share/doc/base-passwd/README)
>   to ease the installation of some services that require that they run
>   under an appropriate user/UID. If you do not intend to install new
>   services, you can safely remove those users who do not own any files
>   in your system and do not run any services. In any case, the default
>   behavior is that UID's from 0 to 99 are reserved in Debian, and UID's
>   from 100 to 999 are created by packages on install (and deleted when
>   the package is purged).

Please take a look at the above link for details on this.

Comment: @Rinzwind, The presence of the groups and users are due to debian. Configuration changes are irrelevant to this question - not a question whether removing these users will make system more secure, but whether they can safely be removed.

Comment: @Rinzwind, The link also provides info about each user and group. This applies to ubuntu as is.

Answer (score -1):

No you cant, those users are there because of some program are using it. To harden your server, remove unnecessary program and it will remove the user tied to it as well as part of the removal process.

Comment: This does not provide accurate answering of the question.  There can be many hundreds of reasons why 'old users' are left on the system, including that 'the previous administrators forgot to remove them', and 'these were employees who had logins on the server for administrative tasks but they're no longer with the company'.  It does NOT mean the users are there because some program is using them.  (This does not apply to the system built-in users)